# Create Global-Internal-LB with NEG in GKE (accessible )

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gke-networking, gcp-load-balancer

I have a serving-app (internal, not exposed to the internet) deployed on GKE with neg-ingress and service. Let's say in the us-west-1 region.

**Issue:**
The app is only accessible in the same region, and not across the region.
The services calling from us-east-1 and other regions cannot access the serving-app deployed in us-west-1.

I know I can use the below annotations in the normal Service manifest(non-NEG ingress) to make the LoadBalancer Internal and accessible across the regions:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: serving-app
  labels:
    app: serving-app
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
    networking.gke.io/internal-load-balancer-allow-global-access: "true"
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": false}'
spec:
  selector:
    app: serving-app
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: "a.b.c.d"
```

But for my below set-up for the same app, I am not able to access the serving-app across the regions:

```
# NEG-Service Manifest

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: serving-app
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "serving-app-backend-config"}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: serving-app
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```

```
# NEG-Ingress Manifest
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: serving-app-neg-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.regional-static-ip-name: "serving-app-neg-static-ip"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: serving-app
      port:
        number: 80
```

- I couldn't find any annotation to make the LB global, as was possible in the first case
- I am also not able to edit the LB to make it Global from the GCP-Console too.
- Couldn't find any documentation, supporting the same.

Is there any way to make the NEG-Ingress LB accessible across the regions (keeping it internal only, not exposing it to the internet)?
Is it even possible to do this? or any workaround for this?

Comment: Why not  vpc peering?

Comment: @Adiii vpc peering is present. I am able to access every other gcp-vm and k8s-service, across the regions...only neg-ingress is not accessible.

Comment: vpc peering is used to peer two vpc's. In your case is everything on the same vpc ?

Comment: So the two methods you have tried are totally different from each other. Using a Kubernetes Service of Type LoadBalancer will deploy a Layer 4 (Aka TCP/UDP) LoadBalancer for you. These are Regional by default but you can add the annotation (networking.gke.io/internal-load-balancer-allow-global-access) to make them accessible globally. The second method using Ingress deploys an L7 LB (aka HTTP(s)), with the annotation (kubernetes.io/ingress.class) it becomes an Internal loadbalancer which can only be accessed from clients in the same region. L7 Internal Loadbalancer DO NOT support Global Access

Comment: You can find more into in this page https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress. The paragraph you can about is "Since the internal HTTP(S) load balancer is a regional load balancer, the virtual IP (VIP) is only accessible from a client within the same region and VPC. After retrieving the load balancer VIP, you can use tools (for example, curl) to issue HTTP GET calls against the VIP from inside the VPC."

Answer (score 0):

I tried recreating this concern and tried both annotations. What I noticed from the yaml that you shared specifically in service you are using `cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"`

In my end based from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#minimum_service_requirements) the annotation will depend on the GKE version that you are using. In my replication I used `networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"` and it worked.

Comment: That annotation is for TCP/UDP load-balancer, and not HTTP/L7 Laodbalancer, which gets created in case of NEG.

Comment: I see, sorry for not noticing that. Regarding this concern global access using L7 load balancer is not yet applicable. However this kind of idea has already been reported as a feature request. You can check this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/174752983) 

Since the concern is also the same as yours you can also star the link. You can check this information from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list).